# Reactjs. Product detail page not working as expected

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to write a detail page for a product.

```
function ProductDetail() {

  const product = useGetProducts(`${API}/6`);

  console.log(product);
  
  return (
    <>
      <h1>ProductDetail</h1>
      <ProductItem product={product}/>
    </>
  );
}


const useGetProducts = (API) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios(API);
      setProducts(response.data)
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return products;
}
```

If i uncomment :

```
<ProductItem product={product}/>
```

Then at console.log I can see the product fetched, but if not then I see an empty array

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `await` for asynchronous call in your effect:

```js
useEffect(async () => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const response = await axios(API);
        setProducts(response.data)
    }
    await fetchData();
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks,

I get an error on console, react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.

It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately:

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // You can await here
    const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state

and the same errors occurs